# calendar, more efficient code

Tags: variable, calendar, themes

the goal:
-show the remainder of the current month's events always
-when end of month is near (after the 18th, for example), also show the upcoming month's events

this is what i have presently, which works:

```
{if {current_time format="%d"} > 18}  
  {exp:calendar:cal calendar_id="5057" date_range_start="today" show_months="2" pad_short_weeks="n"}
{if:else}
  {exp:calendar:cal calendar_id="5057" date_range_start="today" show_months="1" pad_short_weeks="n"}
{/if}
```

however, it's not terribly efficient, when all i really want to do is toggle the show_months="1" to "2" -- and the template doesn't like that i have two opened {exp} and only one closed {/exp}

thought i could get away with:

```
show_months="{if {current_time format="%d"} > 18}2{if:else}1{/if}"
```

but that just fails silently. any tips?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't works because this conditional [isn't a simple one](http://johndwells.com/blog/when-a-simple-conditional-isnt), so the template parser tries to parse the `exp:calendar:cal` before the conditional.

Simple conditionals looks like this:

```
{if foo == "bar"}
```

They are parsed before at the stage 13 on [Rendering stages](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html#rendering-stages).

Everything else are advanced conditionals, parsed at stage 18.

So, `{if {current_time format="%d"} > 18}[...]{if:else}[...]{/if}` and `{if {current_time format="%d"} > "18"}[...]{/if} {if {current_time format="%d"} < "19"}[...]{/if}` looks like the same, but, for the EECMS template engine, they aren't.

Please, try this:

```
{exp:calendar:cal calendar_id="5057"
    date_range_start="today"
    {if {current_time format="%d"} > "18"}  
        show_months="2"
    {/if}
    {if {current_time format="%d"} < "19"}  
        show_months="1"
    {/if}
    pad_short_weeks="n"
    parse="inward"
}
    [...]
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

I never tried to use a `string` after a `>`, but I can't test now. Please, test.

Take a look at the [EECMS parsing order](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html) to understand better what is happening.

Comment: I gonna update my answer.

Comment: i really appreciate the continued attempts, but this only outputs a show_months="1" no matter what numbers i input in the variables. i even tried using %j to show a single digit number without the leading 0 that %d uses. but it's no use.

Comment: Please, try using `formta="%j"` and `18`, instead of `"18"`.

Comment: i tried it with and without quotes, with %d and %j, with and without the if:else. it always chooses the latter variable, no matter what numbers i enter. (ie: testing with 1 instead of 18 to try and force the first variable.)

Comment: so frustrating. i tried to do this with PHP instead, thinking i could avoid the EE conditional altogether.

    {exp:calendar:cal calendar_id="5057"
      date_range_start="today"
    <?php $today = date('j');
      if ($today > 18) { // if later in the month, show next month as well ?>
      show_months="2"
    <?php } else { // show the rest of this month only ?>
      show_months="1"
    <?php } ?>
      pad_short_weeks="n"
    }

this **always** produces the the 2nd option, no matter the variables. if i run the same conditional and put the full {embed} code instead, i get the opposite.